# International flight/Narita Airport/Baggage Claim

Tags: luggage, international-travel, nrt

I am traveling from Taipei to Houston on the same day but I have a connection flight in Narita (Tokyo, Japan) with a different airline. So my flight will be the following:

TAIPEI - DEPARTURE @8:45 hrs with ANA

NARITA AIRPORT - ARRIVAL @13 hrs

I have to claim my baggage

NARITA AIRPORT - DEPARTURE @16:40 hrs with UNITED AIRLINES

My question is that if I have to get a transit visa if I claim the baggage, because I have seen in the webpage that there's a transit counter so I don't have to go out of the airport but there's nothing about the baggage claiming when you have connecting flights with different airlines.
Do you know how is the procedure on this matter?

Comment: you mention they are different airlines, but are they two separate flights on different bookings?  I presume they are separate bookings as you say you have to claim you baggage, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I made a different booking for UNITED AIRLINES, but I called the airline (UNITED) and they told me that ANA can check the baggage til my final destination just had to show my ticket, but I was not really convinced with that answer...

Answer (score 6):

I returned from my trip and I was able without a visa to pass security through the transit section in Narita, ANA was able to send my luggage to my final destination even if I had a connecting flight with United Airlines in Narita with a different booking.

Answer (score 5):

ANA and United are partner airlines in the Star Alliance.  You should be able to check your baggage all the way through from Taipei to Houston.

If you have one booking/ticket they will do it automatically.  If you have two separate bookings, then you will need to show your second ticket so they can enter the necessary baggage tracking details.

If by some weird chance that you can not check your bags through, then you would need to follow the signs for immigration, enter Japan (visa rules dependent on your nationality), claim your baggage, head up to check in, check in, then proceed through immigration back into the departure area.  There is no "transit" short cut.

Comment: the Star Alliance FAQ page http://www.staralliance.com/en/faqs/flight-and-baggage/ states: "the flights must be included in the same booking record"

Comment: Based on personal experience, Star Alliance partners will check bags through on separate tickets.

Comment: I called UNITED and they told me that ANA will be able to check my luggage to my final destination just showing my UNITED ticket. Hope that works. Thanks